# Изменение данных в БД в приложении

Tags: php, android, phpmyadmin

Есть приложение в котором есть регистрация и логирование пользователя, при регистрации он водит разные данные например Фамилия, Имя, Отчество, они вносятся в БД на phpMyAdmin, при логировании в свой профиль видит все данные которые вводил при регистрации, так вот можно ли эти данные поменять в самом приложении и что бы они от редактировались в самой БД.

Пример
Я во время регистрации не правильно ввел фамилию, и хочу ее поменять, для этого я захожу в свой профиль, там есть кнопка редактировать данные, я нажимаю на неё и могу поменять фамилию на ту которую мне нужно. Как это реализовать? Именно смену данных? Есть как-нибудь простой пример как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Надо отправить данные в РНР. Из РНР записать в БД.Примеров в интернете - миллионов пятьсот. из каждого утюга тебя научат работать с базой данных из РНР.

Comment: Вот здесь можно почитать [редактирование данных в PHP](https://metanit.com/web/php/7.6.php)